# How to include file when a function called in php

Tags: php

I know this is a totally rubbish kind of question but i am totally confuse and i don't know how to include file when a function called in php.

for example i have a dir name as **Function** which is containing 100's of file with the function name like **myfunction.php** and this file has **myfunction();**

so when i called this function like

```
include 'Function/'.$functionName.'.php'; // here file should auto include.
myfunction(); // i called this function here so when i called this function then myfunction.php file should auto include in above line
```

is there any way to include file automatically.
please suggest me a way.

Comment: what error you saw? if there is a valid file named according to `$functionName` in `Function` directory, then you should not have any issue

Comment: There is not, what you could do is create an includes.php that has all the includes that you need and call that.   The function will not auto include unless $functionName is declared above the include line.

Comment: *"when a function is called"* - `function myfunction() { include here }` and call the function - if that's what the question is about. TBH, am having a hard time wrapping my head around your question.

Comment: There's an answer below; see that. It looks promising.

Comment: sounds like OP wants an auto-loader for arbitrary function calls. basically `if (!function_exists($foo) { include($foo . '.php'); $foo();`

Answer (score 2):

Calling an undefined function throws an undefined error, which will halt execution when it happens. Even if you could catch the error, you couldn't then return the function output to the original variable.

My recommendation, include all functions at the start of the page:

```
foreach (glob("Function/*.php") as $filename)
{
    include $filename;
}
```

Otherwise, you'd have to do something like this, manually for each call:

```
try {
    $ret = example_function();
} catch ( Exception $e) {
    include('Function/example_function.php');
    $ret = example_function();
}
```

You could however, create a custom function which would do that:

```
function myFunction()
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    $func_name = array_shift($args);

    if ( !function_exists($func_name) ) {
        include('Function/' . $func_name . '.php');
    }

    return call_user_func_array($func_name, $args);
}
```

You would then have to call your functions with `myFunction('testFunction', $param1, $param2)`.

If you're loading classes, this becomes easier. You can use [PHP autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to accomplish this task:

> Many developers writing object-oriented applications create one PHP source file per class definition. One of the biggest annoyances is having to write a long list of needed includes at the beginning of each script (one for each class).
>
> In PHP 5, this is no longer necessary. The spl_autoload_register() function registers any number of autoloaders, enabling for classes and interfaces to be automatically loaded if they are currently not defined. By registering autoloaders, PHP is given a Last Chance to load the class or interface before it fails with an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use method overloading, [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

```
class MethodTest
{
    public function __call($functionName, $arguments)
    {
        include 'Function/'.$functionName.'.php';
        return $functionName($arguments); 
    }

}


$obj = new MethodTest;
$obj->myCustomFunc("myCustomParams")
```